# How to continue the installation process after freeze?

Tags: installation, asus, amd-processor

I have a pc with a `MOBO asus m5a99fx pro r2.0`, `CPU AMD FX-4100`, `2X4GB CORSAIR VENGENCE 1600 MHZ`, `GC NVIDIA GT430 2GB`.

I tried so many times to install Ubuntu in my pc, from 10.04 to 12.10, in 32b or 64b from LiveUSB or LiveDVD (I burned a lot of CDs & DVDs).

After the setup shows me that I have 4Gb free in the HDD and I have internet connection I press continue to begin the installation and nothing happens. The setup freeze and it happens no matter which version I use.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: does the LIVE CD/DVD work?

Comment: YES, i used in mi pc as a live cd and works perfectly but when i try to install from the icon just show me that i have the 4 gb and the internet conection, i don mark the extra codecs, when i press the button just freeze, don show me my hard disk to make my partitions

Comment: and i used all the distros i burn in other laptop and start the installation normally

Comment: sounds like a hardware issue then.

Comment: Are you still experiencing this problem?

Answer (score 2):

In the bios there is a windows secure boot option you have to change. This mother board is built for windows and requires some BIOS tweaks.